# Autocompletion breaks when using function-as-variable syntax

Tags: swift4

Whenever I define a function as a variable I lose auto-completion.  If say I write code like this:

```
typealias MyFunction = (_ foo: Int) -> Void

let myFunction: MyFunction = { foo in
    print(foo) // shows <<error type>>
}
```

`foo` will be `<<error type>>` in the pop up.

This in Xcode 9.3

Comment: Works on my machine. If you can reproduce this reliably, I'd suggest filing a bug at https://bugreporter.apple.com.

Comment: I did earlier today.